# HTML5 appcache, Get a list of cached files in the client

Tags: javascript, html, html5-appcache

In my project, I'm trying to use HTML5 appcache to cache static resources like CSS and JS, and "user specific" files such as images and videos. When I say user specific images/videos, I'm trying to have separate files for each user and I need to control order of the file download as well.

Given the scenario, my manifest file will be dynamically loaded for every user. Is there a way where I can get a list of resources that are already cached in client side?

If not, is is possible to read the ".appcache" file in client?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can use AJAX request to get the manifest cache file and then read it.

However, this does not guarantee that the browser in the question has the files available.

Below is an sample code

- Which checks if we have cached HTML5 app or not
- If we are not in a cached state then count loaded resources in the manifest and display a progress bar according to the manifest cache entry count (total) and do a manual AJAX GET request for all URLs to warm up the cache. The browser will do this itself, but this way we can get some progress information out of the process.
- When cache is in a known good state, move forward

Disclaimer: not tested to work since 2010

```
/**
 * HTML5 offline manifest preloader.
 * 
 * Load all manifest cached entries, so that they are immediately available during the web app execution.
 * Display some nice JQuery progress while loading.
 * 
 * @copyright 2010 mFabrik Research Oy
 * 
 * @author Mikko Ohtamaa, http://opensourcehacker.com
 */

/**
 * Preloader class constructor.
 * 
 * Manifest is retrieved via HTTP GET and parsed.
 * All cache entries are loaded using HTTP GET.
 * 
 * Local storage attribute "preloaded" is used to check whether loading needs to be performed,
 * as it is quite taxing operation.
 * 
 * To debug this code and force retrieving of all manifest URLs, add reloaded=true HTTP GET query parameter:
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * @param {Function} endCallback will be called when all offline entries are loaded
 * 
 * @param {Object} progressMonitor ProgressMonitor object for which the status of the loading is reported.
 */
function Preloader(endCallback, progressMonitor, debug) {

    if(!progressMonitor) {
        throw "progressMonitor must be defined";
    }

    this.endCallback = endCallback;
    this.progressMonitor = progressMonitor;
    this.logging = debug; // Flag to control console.log() output   
}

Preloader.prototype = { 
    /**
     * Load HTML5 manifest and parse its data
     * 
     * @param data: String, manifest file data
     * @return Array of cache entries 
     * 
     * @throw: Exception if parsing fails
     */
    parseManifest : function(data) {

        /* Declare some helper string functions 
         * 
         * http://rickyrosario.com/blog/javascript-startswith-and-endswith-implementation-for-strings/
         *
         */
        function startswith(str, prefix) {
            return str.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
        }

        var entries = [];

        var sections = ["NETWORK", "CACHE", "FALLBACK"];
        var currentSection = "CACHE";

        var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
        var i;

        if(lines.length <= 1) {
            throw "Manifest does not contain text lines";
        }

        var firstLine = lines[0];
        if(!(startswith(firstLine, "CACHE MANIFEST"))) {
            throw "Invalid cache manifest header:" + firstLine;
        }

        for(i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {

            var line = lines[i];
            this.debug("Parsing line:" + line);

            // If whitespace trimmed line is empty, skip it
            line = jQuery.trim(line);
            if(line == "") {
                continue;
            }

            if(line[0] == "#") {
                // skip comment;
                continue;
            }

            // Test for a new section
            var s = 0;
            var sectionDetected = false;
            for(s=0; s<sections.length; s++) {
                var section = sections[s];
                if(startswith(line, section + ":")) {
                    currentSection = section;
                    sectionDetected = true;
                }
            }

            if(sectionDetected) {
                continue;
            }

            // Otherwise assume we can check for cached url
            if(currentSection == "CACHE") {
                entries.push(line); 
            }

        }

        return entries;
    },

    /**
     * Manifest is given as an <html> attribute.
     */
    extractManifestURL : function() {
        var url = $("html").attr("manifest");
        if(url === null) {
            alert("Preloader cannot find manifest URL from <html> tag");
            return null;
        }
        return url;
    },

    isPreloaded : function() {
        // May be null or false
        return localStorage.getItem("preloaded") == true;
    },

    setPreloaded : function(status) {
        localStorage.setItem("preloaded", status);
    },

    /**
     * Check whether we need to purge offline cache.
     * 
     */
    isForcedReload : function() {

        // http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html
        function getQueryParam(name) {
          name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
          var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
          var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
          var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
          if (results == null) {
            return "";
          } else {
            return results[1];
          }
        }

        if(getQueryParam("reload") == "true") {
            return true;
        }   

        return false;
    },

    /**
     * Do everything necessary to set-up offline application
     */
    load : function() {

        this.debug("Entering preloader");

        if (window.applicationCache) {
            this.debug("ApplicationCache status " + window.applicationCache.status);
            this.debug("Please see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#applicationcache");
        } else {
            this.silentError("The browser does not support HTML5 applicationCache object");
            return; 
        }

        var cold;

        if(this.isPreloaded()) {
            // We have succesfully completed preloading before
            // ...move forward

            forceReload = this.isForcedReload(); 
            if (forceReload == true) {
                applicationCache.update();
            } else {
                this.endCallback();
                return;
            }

            cold = false;
        } else {
            cold = true;
        }

        var url = this.extractManifestURL();
        if(url === null) {
            return;
        }

        this.progressMonitor.startProgress(cold);

        $.get(url, {}, jQuery.proxy(manifestLoadedCallback, this));

        function manifestLoadedCallback(data, textStatus, xhr) { 
            this.debug("Manifest retrieved");
            var text = data;
            manifestEntries = this.parseManifest(text); 
            this.debug("Parsed manifest entries:" + manifestEntries.length);
            this.populateCache(manifestEntries);
        }
    },


    /**
     * Bootstrap async loading of cache entries.
     * 
     * @param {Object} entrires
     */
    populateCache : function(entries) {
        this.manifestEntries = entries;
        this.currentEntry = 0;
        this.maxEntry = entries.length;
        this.loadNextEntry();
    },

    /**
     * Make AJAX request to next entry and update progress bar.
     * 
     */
    loadNextEntry : function() {

        if(this.currentEntry >= this.maxEntry) {
            this.setPreloaded(true);
            this.progressMonitor.endProgress();
            this.endCallback();
        }

        var entryURL = this.manifestEntries[this.currentEntry];
        this.debug("Loading entry: " + entryURL);

        function done() {
            this.currentEntry++;
            this.progressMonitor.updateProgress(this.currentEntry, this.maxEntries);
            this.loadNextEntry();   
        }

        this.debug("Preloader fetching:" + entryURL + " (" + this.currentEntry + " / " + this.maxEntry + ")");

        $.get(entryURL, {}, jQuery.proxy(done, this));
    },

    /**
     * Write to debug console
     * 
     * @param {String} msg
     */
    debug : function(msg) {
        if(this.logging) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    },

    /**
     * Non-end user visible error message
     *
     * @param {Object} msg
     */
    silentError : function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
};

function ProgressMonitor() {

}

ProgressMonitor.prototype = {

    /**
     * Start progress bar... initialize as 0 / 0
     */
    startProgress : function(coldVirgin) {
        $("#web-app-loading-progress-monitor").show();
        if(coldVirgin) {
            $("#web-app-loading-progress-monitor .first-time").show();
        }
    },

    endProgress : function() {
    },

    updateProgress : function(currentEntry, maxEntries) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @mikko. I had somewhat similar solution but it's not that reliable. This is what I try to do... If the client knows the files that it has already downloaded, then it could send the names of back to server, where server will add the whatever necessary (remaining) files to the manifest file. (I'm trying to do this one by one, then I can control the order of the downloading).

Answer (score 0):

I have also been working on a solution for discovering which file is being cached, and have come up with the following.

.htaccess wrapper for the directory we are grabbing files to appcache.

```
#.htaccess
<FilesMatch "\.(mp4|mpg|MPG|m4a|wav|WAV|jpg|JPG|bmp|BMP|png|PNG|gif|GIF)$">
    SetHandler autho
</FilesMatch>
Action autho /www/restricted_access/auth.php
```

then my auth.php file returns the file (in chunks) to the browser, but also logs at the same time to the server (I use a DB table) with an earlier declared APPID.

That way while the 'progress' event is detected, an AJAX call can be made to retrieve the last entry for APPID, which contains the file name and how much data has been sent.

The advantage of using this method is that its transparent to other methods accessing the files in the '.htaccess wrapped' folder, and in my case also includes authentication.

When not authorized to access a file for whatever reason I return 'Not Authorized' headers.